# PHP regular expression to extract number from html code

Tags: php, regex

In an html source code with a fragment like this:

```
of <span class="important">721,006</span>
```

I want to extract number `721,006`. There could be more than one  so I need the word "of" to get the real one.

Could you help me?

Comment: Is this the whole source you are given, or have you parsed that out of something already?

Comment: This is me *helping* you: [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). `$false = function() { return $SO === 'free code'; }`

Comment: I agree with @rdlowrey asking things that simple means that you should start reading the documentation..

Comment: A bit more info would be helpful. Is there always a comma?  What kind of data is around this span? Is. At the moment a simple preg_match('/([0-9,]*)/', $matches) would suffice..

Comment: No, not you, it was SERPRO and the others who helped, you didn't. It's clear I'm asking for help, I'm not good at regular expressions

Comment: Well, you're right I'm asking for help, I've been working and reading documentation of regular expressions for 2 or 3 years, I'm sorry, I'm just not good for it, I spent more than 20 minutes with this stupid one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is a very simple regex, since you don't add any extra requirements:

```
#<span class="important">([0-9,]+)</span>#
```

[Example](http://xrg.es/#trsh68)